# FFmpeg: "filter_complex" results in worse quality than "vf"

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to do some complex video transcoding (such as concatenating multiple files).  To do this, I've been trying to use the *filter_complex*, but I've noticed a slight drop in quality from what I saw earlier using the normal video filter.

To double-check, I boiled down my command to a simple transcode -- one using *filter_complex* and one just using the *vf* -- and I've confirmed that the output of the complex filter is noticeably blurry compared to the output of the normal video filter.  I can't find any FFmpeg documentation explaining this... does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get *filter_complex* to output the same quality video as *vf* ?

**Command using the normal video filter (vf):**

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map_chapters -1 -f mpegts -an -sn -map 0:0 -vf "[in]yadif=deint=interlaced[out]" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 2 -b:v 800k output.ts
```

**FFmpeg Output:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfaac --enable-libvpx --enable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --disable-decoder=prores --disable-decoder=prores_lgpl --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags=-I/local/build/include --extra-libs=-lfdk-aac --extra-ldflags=-L/local/build/lib --prefix=/local/build/install
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 741 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 604 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] No 608/708 caption insertion into sei user data.
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] frame MB size (54x30) > level limit (396)
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] MB rate (48600) > level limit (11880)
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 2.0
Output #0, mpegts, to 'output.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], q=-1--1, 800 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  300 fps=179 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1059kB time=00:00:10.03 bitrate= 864.9kbits/s speed=   6x    
video:949kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 11.660099%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] frame I:2     Avg QP:23.16  size: 26978
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] frame P:298   Avg QP:23.09  size:  3079
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] mb I  I16..4: 44.3%  0.0% 55.7%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] mb P  I16..4:  1.1%  0.0%  0.5%  P16..4: 28.7%  8.4%  2.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:59.3%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] final ratefactor: 22.63
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.8% 62.8% 23.0% inter: 7.2% 14.8% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 39% 11% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 29% 16%  5%  6%  7%  6%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 29% 18%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x138a99e0] kb/s:777.19
```

**Command using the complex filter:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map_chapters -1 -f mpegts -filter_complex "[0:v:0]yadif=deint=interlaced[v0];[v0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=0[cat_v]" -an -sn -map "[cat_v]" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 2 -b:v 800k output.ts
```

**FFmpeg Output:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfaac --enable-libvpx --enable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --disable-decoder=prores --disable-decoder=prores_lgpl --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags=-I/local/build/include --extra-libs=-lfdk-aac --extra-ldflags=-L/local/build/lib --prefix=/local/build/install
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 741 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 604 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] No 608/708 caption insertion into sei user data.
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] frame MB size (54x30) > level limit (396)
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] MB rate (48600) > level limit (11880)
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] profile Constrained Baseline, level 2.0
Output #0, mpegts, to 'output.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], q=-1--1, 800 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> yadif
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  300 fps=179 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1059kB time=00:00:10.03 bitrate= 864.9kbits/s speed=   6x    
video:949kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 11.660099%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] frame I:2     Avg QP:23.16  size: 26978
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] frame P:298   Avg QP:23.09  size:  3079
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] mb I  I16..4: 44.3%  0.0% 55.7%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] mb P  I16..4:  1.1%  0.0%  0.5%  P16..4: 28.7%  8.4%  2.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:59.3%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] final ratefactor: 22.63
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.8% 62.8% 23.0% inter: 7.2% 14.8% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 39% 11% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 29% 16%  5%  6%  7%  6%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 29% 18%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x81f5200] kb/s:777.19
```

Comment: Show the complete console output.

Comment: As per the readouts, the video outputs are identical.

Comment: You would think so, but they're not... that's my whole point

Comment: Image from vf: https://postimg.org/image/6o2pfo34n/   Image from filter_complex: https://postimg.org/image/uds54d1hz/   The second one is clearly more blurry than the first one.

Comment: I believe that your player may be introducing some glitch here. Run `ffmpeg -i vf.ts -i filtercomplex.ts -lavfi ssim -f null -` and report the values printed at the end of the command execution.

Comment: I blame the player because the statistics from the encoder for the two commands are identical. If one was blurrier, the odds of those values being identical would be astronomical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.  It's because the default scaling algorithm changed from `bicubic` to `bilinear`.  All I had to do was add `flags=bicubic` and it now looks the same.

Comment: im facing the same issue, can you please advise where in the complex filter did you add these flags